# How to manually install e(fx)clipse addon for Java Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, windowbuilder

I need the e(fx)clipse Window Builder to develop my application. I am using Windows XP Java 8 is unsupported. I must use an older version of e(fx)clipse to that supports Java 7. I've looked everywhere on how to do this but all sources are leading me to installing the latest version via the (Install New Software) feature in Eclipse. This doesn't work for me as I cannot find the correct p2 link for older versions of the software. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the steps for offline install plugins.

1. Open [WindowBuilder Pro download page](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php), click the link under **Zipped Update Site**. If you are using Eclipse 3.8, you can download WB v1.7 for offline install.
2. If you don't want to install extra plugins, select menu item `Windows > Preference`. Then select tree item  `Install/Update > Available Software Sites`, uncheck all items and press `OK` to close it.
3. Unpack the downloaded zip file to a folder (do NOT use the file expleror of Windows...)
4. Select menu item `Help > Install New Software...`. Click `Add...` button and `Local...` button to select the folder in previous steps.
5. Eclipse will list avaiable features for install. You can select the features and click `Next` button. You may get errors such as:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: SWT Designer XWT Support (requires Eclipse WTP/WST) 1.7.0.r42x201405021548 (org.eclipse.wb.xwt.feature.feature.group 1.7.0.r42x201405021548)
  Missing requirement: WindowBuilder Core for XML GUI's 1.7.0.r42x201405021458 (org.eclipse.wb.core.xml 1.7.0.r42x201405021458) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: SWT Designer XWT Support 1.7.0.r42x201405021548 (org.eclipse.wb.xwt 1.7.0.r42x201405021548)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wb.core.xml 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: SWT Designer XWT Support (requires Eclipse WTP/WST) 1.7.0.r42x201405021548 (org.eclipse.wb.xwt.feature.feature.group 1.7.0.r42x201405021548)
    To: org.eclipse.wb.xwt [1.7.0.r42x201405021548]
```

In this case, you can unselect features: **WindowBuilder Core for XML** and **SWT Designer XWT Support**. Since they depend on the plugins of Eclipse webtools... (Or install Eclipse webtools before install WB)

Once all errors gone, accept the license agreement and click `Next` to finish the installation. Then you can use WB after restarting Eclipse.